# efficient way for replacing sub-arrays within numpy array - numpy.put or similar?

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, matplotlib

I have a long list, called "colours", containing tuples of length 4. 
I need to substitute some of these tuples by other tuples (or more specifically, all the tuples that I need to replace should be replaced by the tuple (1.,0.,0.,1.), corresponding to the colour 'red' in matplotlib). I know the indices of the tuples I need to substitute - stored in a list called "indices", of length "li".

Of course I could use:

```
for i in range(li):
  colours[indices[i]] = (1.,0.,0.,1.)
```

but because the list "colours" is 400*400 elements long, this substitution takes fairly long. I was wondering whether there is a quicker and more elegant way to do this?

I tried to convert "colours" into a numpy.array (which still works fine for matplotlib), and then using the numpy.put method:

```
n.put(colours, indices, [(1.,0.,0.,1.)]*li)
```

but this does not work, because instead of replacing the whole tuple, n.put just replaces a sub-element of the tuple (i.e. a single number) within colours by another number from the (1.,0.,0.,1.)-tuple.

Does anyone have any suggestions what to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you convert `colours` to a NumPy array, then you could use so-called ["advanced (integer) indexing"](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer) to do the assignment:

```
colours = np.array(colours)
colours[indices, :] = (1, 0, 0, 1)
```

Comment: Hmm, sorry, maybe I wasn't clear - colours[li,:] only substitutes the tuple with index "li", but I need to substitute all tuples with indices in this list called "indices" (and li=length(indices))

Comment: Oops, I misread the variable names. However, it will work with the list `indices`.